# Salesforce multi organization access

Tags: salesforce, apex

I want to access Salesforce Organization data from my Application (Python) through API. I want to access data from multiple organizations in Salesforce in this case should I have to ask an user (one user) from each organization to register their user name and password with my application?

What is the right way of achieving this?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Is this a back-end application that runs batch jobs, etc? Or is this a custom tool that individual users will use to access data across multiple orgs (where they have a separate username for each org)?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you should avoid having users enter their credentials directly into your application. If possible, allow them to use one of the oauth flows where they only provide the credentials to Salesforce and then a token is issued to the application for API access.

For a long running process you can get a refresh token that will allow you to re-establish the session as required.

See

- [OAuth 2.0 User-Agent Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&language=en_US)
- [OAuth 2.0 Web Server Authentication Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&language=en_US)
- [OAuth 2.0 Refresh Token Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm&language=en_US)

Incidentally, the [Salesforce Stackexchange](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) is a great place to ask Salesforce specific questions.